# Publicly search Twitter users Category-wise

Tags: android, twitter

In my app the user may try a search for twitter users category wise (ex. film stars, sports persons, scientist etc.) and **they may try this without login**.

I need the result in xml, so that my app can parse it. Now the problem is I need the proper URL to perform the search in my app as follows:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL); ... and so on.
```

**I need the proper URL.**

I have the following URLs but either they need authentication or they are not working. I have searched Twitter developers site & stackoverflow, but get no relevant topic. URLs as follows:

1. http://api.twitter.com/1/users/search.xml?q=sports+persons
   [**ERROR:** 07-05 16:25:43.276: W/DefaultRequestDirector(985): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {oauth=WWW-Authenticate: OAuth realm="http://api.twitter.com"}
   07-05 16:25:43.286: E/TweetHandler(985):  Could not authenticate you.
   07-05 16:25:43.297: E/TweetHandler(985):  /1/users/search.xml?q=sports+persons
   07-05 16:25:43.297: E/TweetHandler(985):  
   ]
2. http://twitter.com/#!/search/users/sports+persons [not working]

Please help me to find the proper URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the error message you're getting - you need to be authenticated before searching.

Read the [users/search documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/search).

Your search URL is correct, but you will need to sign the request first.

Comment: We can get a persons tweet feeds without authentication. Same way I need a solution to search the users without authentication.

Comment: You cannot. Read the documentation - it requires authentication.